# Similar language features to compare with Perl and Ruby __END__

Tags: language-agnostic, syntax, programming-languages, comparison, language-comparisons

**Background**

Perl and Ruby have the `__END__` and `__DATA__` tokens that allow embedding of arbitrary data directly inside a source code file.

Although this practice may not be well-advised for general-purpose programming use, it is pretty useful for "one-off" quick scripts for routine tasks.

**Question:**

What other programming languages support this same or similar feature, and how do they do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl supports the `__DATA__` marker, which you can access the contents of as though it were a regular file handle.

Comment: Yeah, ruby does the same. I think the implementations for this language feature are essentially identical for ruby and perl.

Answer (score 1):

Fortran has a DATA statement that sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: The Fortran DATA statement is more akin to static variable initialization in C.  It's not really the same.

Answer (score 1):

Basic on the VIC20 and C64 had a "*Data*" command that worked something like this

```
100 DATA 1,2,3
110 DATA 4,5,6
```

Data could be read via a READ command.

I no longer have a c64 to test my code on.

Answer (score 1):

SAS has the `datalines` construct which is used for embedding an external data file inside the source program, e.g. in the following program, there are 5 datalines (the terminator is the semi-colon on a line by itself)

```
data output;
  input name $ age;
  datalines;
Jim 14
Sarah 11
Hannah 9
Ben 9
Timothy 4
;
run;
```

Comment: interesting. that looks similar to the HEREDOC convention: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredoc